# Connecting href from another div to src

Tags: php, html, href, src

I do have a problem, I'm trying to make a video iframe popup which shows the clicked video.

This is the div with the videos;

```
<ul class="video_list">
      <?php
        $result_video = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM guestlist_tvs ORDER BY created DESC LIMIT 16");
        while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result_video)) { 
      ?>
        <li rel='<?php echo $row['video_music_cat'];?>' cat='<?php echo $row['video_cat'];?>'>
        <div class="testtest">
          <a href='http://www.youtube.com/embed/<?php echo $row['youtube_id']; ?>?rel=0&amp;wmode=transparent' class='video_thumb'>
            <div class="video_img_wrapper"><img class='video_img'src="http://img.youtube.com/vi/<?php echo $row['youtube_id']; ?>/maxresdefault.jpg" width='240px' height='160px'>
            <img class="play_button" src="images/play_button.png" alt="play" /></img></div>
            <h3><?php echo $row['title']; ?></h3>
          </a>
         </div>
        </li>
      <?php 
        }
        mysqli_close($con);
      ?>
      </ul>
```

The iframe-popup has this code:

```
<iframe width="854" height="480" src="MYVIDEOLINKHERE" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

What I try to figure out is how I can say the the src of the iframe is the href from the class "testtest".

Thanks in advance

Comment: I think you should jQuery for that.

Comment: Could you give an example, please?

Comment: What API did you use to create the dialog?

Comment: I used this example;

http://www.afs.org/help/snippets/popup-video/

Comment: Please, show the javascript code you already have.

Comment: Nvm anymore, thanks for helping.

I made a javascript code that gets the href value

Answer (score 0):

My solution is using jquery and click event

```
$(document).ready(function() {  
    $('.video_thumb').click(function () {
        alert(this.getAttribute("src"));
    });

});
```

[**JSFIDDLE DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/6tn9o39j/)

Answer (score 0):

Use this jquery in script tag in that page

```
 $(document).ready(function(){

  $(".play_button").click(function(){
     $("iframe").attr("src") =$(this).closest(".testtest").find("a").first().attr("href");




  });





 });
```